# Vertical Scrollbar is stuck to the page

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

On most common browsers and any websites the "scrollbar" vanishes on idle or when you are not scrolling. However, on my website it seems to be stuck to the page. I've been stuck on this problem for a couple days and just can't seem to figure it out.

I've tried the most common answers that are around so I figured it is best described if you just have a look yourself;

http://www.witaminsklep.pl/c.5171732/sca-dev-aconcagua/shopping-local.ssp#

I want the scrollbar to display whenever a user decided to scroll, but disappear when they're not. I believe that this is causing other issues like uneven alignment.. 
How can I fix the scrollbar?

update: I was able to remove the stuck scrollbar. But on Safari it doesn't appear at all now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the scrollbar styled with CSS in shopping_5.css line 3281. So simply remove the following styles:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: 0 0;
  background-color: rgba(77, 82, 86, 0.25);
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-clip: padding-box; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: rgba(77, 82, 86, 0.5); }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: rgba(77, 82, 86, 0.05); }
```

Comment: I removed this and it seemed to fix the problem. What purpose does this code have?

Comment: I am testing this now. On Google Chrome, it works as intended. But on Safari 12.0.1 the scrollbar completely disappears while the function of scrolling works.

Answer (score 0):

On the web scrollbars only "go away" when there isn't enough content to overflow the container (no need for scroll). Hiding scrollbars until a user interaction is a Mac OS (and more recently Win10) feature visible in "most" apps unless the user decides to turn it off at a system level.

Ignoring the debate about the [usability implications](http://uxmag.com/articles/the-extinction-of-the-scrollbar) of hiding scrollbars, you're best off looking for a javascript library to recreate the scrollbars while hiding the system ones.

Comment: This would be way too overwhelming just for a scrollbar. However, I appreciate the feedback.